# problems using multimap in c++

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

```
vector<vector<string>> groupAnagrams(vector<string>& s) {
vector<vector<string>> res;
multimap<string,int> m;
vector<string>::iterator it;
for(it=s.begin();it!=s.end();it++){
    sort((*it).begin(),(*it).end());
}
int i=0;
for(it=s.begin();it!=s.end();it++){
    m.insert(pair<string,int>(*(it),i));
    i++;
}
//sort each string
multimap<string,int>::iterator it;
sort(m.begin(),m.end());
//sort all strings
string st=s[0];
for(it=m.begin();it<m.end();it++){
    vector<string> temp;
    temp.push_back(s);
    if((*it)->first == st){
        temp.push_back((*it)->first);
    }
    res.push_back(temp);
    if((*it)->first != st){
        st=(*it)->first;
    }
}
return res;
}
```

The code is for grouping anagrams. I used multimap for mapping the word to the initial index. sorted the individual word first and then sorted the entire set of words.The error i'm getting is

```
conflicting declaration ‘std::multimap<std::basic_string<char>, int>::iterator it’
```

Comment: you already have a variable called it (`vector<string>::iterator it; `). Call your multimap iterator something else...

Comment: You could rename one of the two things you named `it` as the earlier comment and answers suggest.  But it is better style to limit the scope of each use of `it` rather than vary the name.  `for(auto it=m.begin();it<m.end();it++)` or  `for(multimap<string,int>::iterator it=m.begin();it<m.end();it++)` instead of declaring `it` seperately before use.

Comment: Thanks, I always do make such silly mistakes

Comment: That's not the only error you're getting, and not even the full error. The compiler tells you which line it's on, and also says `previous declaration as ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator it’` and tells you which line that previous declaration is on. So in short, just read the error messages properly.

Comment: For God's sake use typedefs

Comment: @NathanOliver and `auto`, I do not think `auto` would eliminate `typedef` in that unreadable code

Comment: @slava: `for (auto const& val : s)` (and `m`) would work just fine. (sorting the multimap is problematic, though.)

Comment: @rici I am not against `auto`, I am just saying that using `auto` does not eliminate benefits of using typedef in this code.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring the same variable (`it`) twice with different types.  Use a different variable name for one of the declarations.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `it` twice.  first `vector<string>::iterator it;` and then with `multimap<string,int>::iterator it;`.  You will need to rename one of them.